# MySQLi table not being made but others are

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This table is being made

```
$tbl_entertour = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entertour (
                 team_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 tournament_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 provname_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 username VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 p_1_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 p_2_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 p_3_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 p_4_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 p_5_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 p_6_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 ip VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
                 entered DATETIME NOT NULL,
                 UNIQUE KEY username (username)
            )";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $tbl_entertour);    
if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>entertour table created OK :) </h3>";
} else {
    echo "<h3>entertour table NOT created :( </h3>";
}
```

This table is not being made

```
$tbl_provtour = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS provtour (
                 id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                 user_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                 provname_id (16) NOT NULL,
                 tourname VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                 team_total ENUM('0','999999') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                 entered_teaams ENUM('0','999999') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                 game VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                 c_1 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                 c_2 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                 c_3 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                 c_open ('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                 joinopen ('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                 ip VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
                 reg_start DATETIME NOT NULL,
                 reg_end DATETIME NOT NULL,
                 created DATETIME NOT NULL,
                 lastupdated DATETIME NOT NULL,
                 PRIMARY KEY (id),
                 UNIQUE KEY username (user_id)
            )";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $tbl_provtour); 
if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>provtour table created OK :) </h3>";
} else {
    echo "<h3>provtour table NOT created :( </h3>";
}
```

OK I am trying to create the second table in my database and it just doesn't seem to get made and comes back with the 2nd echo. The top table gets made and same with all other tables get made but for some reason this bottom table doesn't.

I am not sure why. I have been looking at it for about 10 minutes now and I just cant seem to find the error.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you try to echo the error and error-code. That might give you helpful insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few errors in the query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS provtour (
 id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 user_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
 provname_id (16) NOT NULL,
 tourname VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
 team_total ENUM('0','999999') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 entered_teaams ENUM('0','999999') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 game VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
 c_1 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
 c_2 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
 c_3 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
 c_open ('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 joinopen ('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 ip VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
 reg_start DATETIME NOT NULL,
 reg_end DATETIME NOT NULL,
 created DATETIME NOT NULL,
 lastupdated DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE KEY username (user_id)
)
```

- provname_id (16) NOT NULL, missing the datatype
- c_open ('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', missing datatype
- joinopen ('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',missing datatype

So you need to provide a datatype

May be as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS provtour (
id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
provname_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
tourname VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
team_total ENUM('0','999999') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
entered_teaams ENUM('0','999999') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
game VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
c_1 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
c_2 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
c_3 VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
c_open ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
joinopen ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
ip VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
reg_start DATETIME NOT NULL,
reg_end DATETIME NOT NULL,
created DATETIME NOT NULL,
lastupdated DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY username (user_id)
);
```

Change the datatype as you want in the above query, I have added varchar and ENUM for those missing types.

Comment: cheers dude. Just slapped myself in the face for missing that. Cheers sometimes another set of eyes to point out an error is what is needed.

Comment: Ha no worries that happens by every one !!